# Ember Data and Handsontable recursion

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handsontable

When a Handsontable is instantiated, it calls a recursive method to build a data schema: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/blob/be8654f78ca84efc982047ca6b399e6c6d99f893/src/dataMap.js#L28, which in turns calls `objectEach`: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/blob/master/src/helpers/object.js#L235-L245

However, with an Ember Data record, it tries to iterate over properties like `store`, which means it gets caught in an endless loop.

Is there any way to bypass the `recursiveDuckSchema` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless Handsontable has some interface to allow pre-parsing data before it reaches the core of the plugin, I would say you may have better luck by transforming your ember-data models into something handsometable understands.

```
let queryParams = //Your query params
let data = this.get('getTheContent'); //Your models
let handsomeData = data.map(function(item, index, enumerable)){
   return { id: item.get('id'), name: item.get('name'), other: item.get('other') }
};
// Result is [{id: 1, name: 'John', other: 'Other'}, {...}]
```